# Output is printed on same line if input beforehand ends in 5.

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I've been doing some of the codeeval challenges and I thought of doing what I expected to be a relatively simple one - fizzbuzz. I was pretty sure I had it working. It takes in a line from the input, the first number fizz, the second buzz and the third the number to count too. Code is:

```py
import sys


def newList(countLen):
    myList = []
    for i in range(0, countLen):
        myList.append(i + 1)
    return myList


def fizzbuzz(z, countLen, myList):
    first = int(z[0])
    second = int(z[1])
    for i in range(0, countLen):
        if int(myList[i]) % first == 0 and int(myList[i]) % second == 0:
            if i == countLen - 1:
                print "FB"
            else:
                print "FB",
        elif int(myList[i]) % first == 0:
            if i == countLen - 1:
                print "F"
            else:
                print "F",
        elif int(myList[i]) % second == 0:
            if i == countLen - 1:
                print "B"
            else:
                print "B",
        else:
            print myList[i],


with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        group = list(line.split())
        count = int(group[-1])
        numList = newList(count)
        fizzbuzz(group, count, numList)
```

Now as unelegant as this code is, I'm sure it works, if my input is

```py
2 12 22
2 18 30
2 7 25
```

my output is

```py
1 F 3 F 5 F 7 F 9 F 11 FB 13 F 15 F 17 F 19 F 21 F
1 F 3 F 5 F 7 F 9 F 11 F 13 F 15 F 17 FB 19 F 21 F 23 F 25 F 27 F 29 F
1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15 F 17 F 19 F B F 23 F 25
```

with no spaces at the end, just like is asked for. However the code fails or partially succeeds each time I submit. I think this may be because if I swap the last 2 inputs around the output looks like

```py
1 F 3 F 5 F 7 F 9 F 11 FB 13 F 15 F 17 F 19 F 21 F
1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15 F 17 F 19 F B F 23 F 25 1 F 3 F 5 F 7 F 9 F 11 F 13 F 15 F 17 FB 19 F 21 F 23 F 25 F 27 F 29 F
```

I have noticed this happens sometimes when number to count too ends in an input ends in 5 (ie 45. I've tried adding new lines at print, but the problem still occurs.
Any help to get everything printing on new lines would be a great help. 
(I'm running the code in the pycharm console if that effects anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a final conditional statement in your `else`
Alter:

```
else:
    print myList[i],
```

to be:

```
else:
    if i == countLen - 1:
        print myList[i]
    else:
        print myList[i],
```

Comment: And that fixes it. I should of realised! Thank you for your help.